Not Able to Launch Anylogic
I have tried installing Anylogic 8.2/8.3/8.4 however not able to launch the Anylogic SW. Each time I launch I get check error message with below error:
!SESSION 2024-07-23 19:09:36.871 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=9.0.1
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64
!ENTRY com.anylogic.graphicaleditor 4 0 2024-07-23 19:09:40.449
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: com.anylogic.graphicaleditor [16]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: com.anylogic.ui
    -> Bundle-SymbolicName: com.anylogic.ui; bundle-version="8.2.0.201710252011"; singleton:="true"
       com.anylogic.ui [36]
         Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: com.anylogic.examples
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:444)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1634)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1613)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1585)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1528)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)

I have installed Anylogic on Windows 11 system & have updated version of Java Installed.

have you tried the latest v8.9 from the website?
